# Show .setError() on a disabled EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In this Activity I have a form that the user needs to input two dates, a start and end dates.

To take a date input I have A `button` which when clicked, will show a `date picker dialog`. When the user has chosen the date it will then output the selected date to a `disabled edittext`

Then when submitting the form it will validate that selected date and show the error with a `.setError()` however since the `EditText` is disabled the error message cannot be seen because it cannot be clicked.

I know that there is the `requestFocus()` however I have another form that contains 4 of these and I think it's too tedious to click submit many times just to see what's wrong with the other three date `EditText`s.

What I hope I can be able to do is when the user clicks on that disabled `EditText` it shows the error that is shown by the `setError()`.

Or is the way I'm doing this is wrong, is there any alternative? Please help me. Also, I'm just a student so I may not know much. Lots of thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    btn_setSyStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            int YEAR = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int MONTH = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int DAY = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog myDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(AdminAddSchoolYear.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYEAR, int selectedMONTH, int selectedDAY) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYEAR);
                    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDAY);

                    String temp = selectedYEAR+"-"+(selectedMONTH+1)+"-"+selectedDAY;
                    setTempDate(temp);

                    edtxt_syStart.setText(getTempDate());
                }
            },YEAR,MONTH,DAY );
            myDatePicker.show();
        }
    });

    btn_setSyEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            int YEAR = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int MONTH = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int DAY = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog myDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(AdminAddSchoolYear.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYEAR, int selectedMONTH, int selectedDAY) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYEAR);
                    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDAY);

                    String temp = selectedYEAR+"-"+(selectedMONTH+1)+"-"+selectedDAY;
                    setTempDate(temp);

                    edtxt_syEnd.setText(getTempDate());
                }
            },YEAR,MONTH,DAY );
            myDatePicker.show();

        }
    });

    btn_submitSY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            checkForm();
        }
    });

private void checkForm() throws ParseException {
    final String tempSYStart = edtxt_syStart.getText().toString();
    final String tempSYEnd = edtxt_syEnd.getText().toString();
    int stage = 0;
    boolean trial1 = false;
    boolean trial2 = false;
    if(tempSYStart.isEmpty())
    {
        edtxt_syStart.setError("Required");
    }
    else
    {
        edtxt_syStart.setError(null);
        trial1 = true;
    }

    if(tempSYEnd.isEmpty())
    {
        edtxt_syEnd.setError("Required");
    }
    else
    {
        edtxt_syEnd.setError(null);
        trial2 = true;
    }

    if(trial1 && trial2)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");

        Date dateSYStart = SDF.parse(tempSYStart);
        Date dateSYEnd = SDF.parse(tempSYEnd);

        if(dateSYEnd.after(dateSYStart))
        {
            //saveDate(); <- just a process where dates are passed to php via volley.

            edtxt_syEnd.setError(null);
        }
        else
        {
            edtxt_syEnd.setError("End date must be AFTER Start date");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: plz add your code

Comment: @MohammadAli I have now added the code

Comment: i can post answer plzz check it @RFA